# RingCentral RingOut trouble

Tags: phone-call, ringcentral, ringout

I’m having some RingOut API trouble. Everything was working out just fine but suddenly about a week ago one of the users claimed that the RingOut functionality was broken and from what I see she is correct. For the life of me I can’t figure out what the problem is. Below is what my request looks like. After polling the call the api errors out claiming that one or two lines is busy when I know for a fact they are not. Any ideas or direction on this would be greatly appreciated

Request URI:
    https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/279578017/extension/279580017/ring-out/Y3MxNjg2OTU1OTIyMDIwMzQ1NDI5QDEwLjE0LjIzLjQw

Post Variables:

```
{"from":{"phoneNumber":"+17606992007","forwardingNumberId":""},"to":{"phoneNumber":"+17602146463"},"callerId":{"phoneNumber":"+17604440557"},"playPrompt":false,"country":{"id":"1”}}
```

Result:

```
{
  "uri" : "https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/279578017/extension/279580017/ring-out/Y3MxNjg2OTU1NTIyNzE2MzY4NDQyQDEwLjE0LjIzLjA",
  "id" : "Y3MxNjg2OTU1NTIyNzE2MzY4NDQyQDEwLjE0LjIzLjA",
  "status" : {
    "callStatus" : "InProgress",
    "callerStatus" : "InProgress",
    "calleeStatus" : "InProgress"
  }
}
```

Result from polling the call:

```
{
  "uri" : "https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/279578017/extension/279580017/ring-out/Y3MxNjg2OTU1OTgxNjMyMzY1NjYwQDEwLjE0LjIzLjQ2",
  "id" : "Y3MxNjg2OTU1OTgxNjMyMzY1NjYwQDEwLjE0LjIzLjQ2",
  "status" : {
    "callStatus" : "CannotReach",
    "callerStatus" : "Busy",
    "calleeStatus" : "InProgress"
  }
}
```

Comment: When I make a RingOut call with `"forwardingNumberId":""`, I get a Status 400 `Parameter [forwardingNumberId] value is invalid` error. That being said, if I remove it I can make calls to AT&T numbers, which I see you're trying to reach as well. Can you call and reach the same numbers with your regular RingCentral endpoint? For example the RingCentral mobile app or softphone? It might be worth creating a support ticket for this item if it's a connectivity issue.

Comment: I can reach the phone numbers fine when I give them a call with a RingCentral phone or outside line. I was thinking that might have been the problem as well. I will try eliminating the forwardingNumberId and see how that works.

Comment: Removing the forwardingNumberId made no difference.

Comment: Our support team will want to trace those calls to see what is happening. You can create and list support ticket using the links at the bottom of our support page: https://developer.ringcentral.com/support.html . You can also join our Glip chat ( http://glipped.herokuapp.com/ ), but please file a support ticket so they can get your call info and trace the call.

Answer (score 1):

I know it sound strange but i had the same error on my app, Removing the +1 from the number fixed the issue for me.

Hope that helps!

[ringcentral](/questions/tagged/ringcentral)

Comment: Remove it from where? Clarify your answer, please.

Comment: Sorry from the phone number in the following           "{"from":{"phoneNumber":"+17606992007","forwardingNumberId":""},"to":{"phoneNumber":"+17602146463"},"callerId":{"phoneNumber":"+17604440557"},"playPrompt":false,"country":{"id":"1”}}"